# Does OpenCL2.2 SPIRV compiler not checking invalid code

Tags: c++, clang, opencl, spir-v

I just used the [reference clang implementation](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIR/tree/spirv-1.1) of OpenCL C++ to compile the source at page 13 of the [specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-2.2-cplusplus.pdf):

```
#include <opencl_def>
#include <opencl_memory>
#include <opencl_vector_load_store>

half bar(half a) { //ok: half built-in type passed by value
 half b = a; //ok: copying half data type
 b += 10.0; // not allowed: arithmetic operation
 // vload should be used or cl_khr_fp16 support enabled
 float f = cl::vload_half<1>(0, &b); // ok
 return a; //ok: return half built-in type
}

kernel void foo(cl::global_ptr<half> pg) { //ok: a global pointer
 // passed from the host
 int offset = 1;
 half *ptr = pg.get() + offset; //ok: half pointer arithmetic
 half b = bar(*ptr); //ok: dereferencing half pointer
 if(b < *ptr) { //not allowed: it is only supported if cl_khr_fp16
 // extension is enabled
 }
}
```

The specs say that there is a line with `half` mutation, which is not valid and thus I was expecting the compilation to fail. Sadly it compiled without any complaint.

Am I understanding something wrong?